# CLLocation - add 2km or 2000m radius to a coordinate

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude, cllocation

How can I add a radius to a `CLLocation` coordinate? What I want is to see what clients are near a specific coordinate.

What I need is to add 2000 meters, or 2km to a coordinate.

How do I do that?

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, you want to a add a 1 dimension value to a 2 dimension value, do you mean calculate the distance between two coordinates?

Comment: @jbat100 No, what I want is to add a radius of 2000 meters to the coordinate: 2000 to latitude and 2000 to longitude, so that subtracting those values, I can compare all the clients coordinates, and get all of them who are within a 2000 meters of my location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "add a radius" to a coordinate. What you can do if you have `CLLocation` objects (say loc1 and loc2), is calculate the distance between them:

```
CLLocationDistance dist = [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2];
```

and see if dist (which is in meters) is more or less than 2000.0.

Converting between coordinate latitudes/longitudes (which are polar coordinates) and distances is complicated, which is why the SDK provides you with this functionality.

Comment: this way, I have to of thru all clients. Imagine I have 40.000 Client objects in CoreData. If I could transform 2000 meters in latitude and longitude, I could make NSPredicate and obtain the result immediately. This way, I have to go thru all Clients, which will take a while in the app... Is there any efficient way?

Comment: you can't transform 2000 meters into latitude and longitude, that's the point. At the equator a longitude change of 180 degrees is about 20000km, at the north pole a longitude change of 180 degrees is 0km. What you can do is pre-calculate the distances and cache them. Or for each client object have a pre-calculated range of valid longitudes and latitudes, then you can use predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distance is small, you can use the equirectangular distance approximation.  This approximation is faster than using the Haversine formula.  So, to get the distance from your reference point (lat1/lon1) to the point your are testing (lat2/lon2), use the formula below.  Important Note: you need to convert all lat/lon points to radians:

```
R = 6371  // radius of the earth in km
x = (lon2 - lon1) * cos( 0.5*(lat2+lat1) )
y = lat2 - lat1
d = R * sqrt( x*x + y*y )
```

If d is less than 2, then your point is within 2km of your reference point.

To efficiently march through your points, order the points on longitude.  Longitudes that are 2 degrees away will be greater than 2km (unless you are near a pole), therefore you don't need to loop through those.

Comment: Until what distance is the formula consistent? The user will be able to choose the distance. What is the max distance? 100km?

Comment: It is more a question of what your accuracy requirements are.